# How can i rotate a block around a ball?

Tags: modeling

i'm trying to rotate a block around a ball in blender 2.77 using armature.
the ball deforms. how can i fix this?
[image: it doesnt work how i want it to.]

so i was trying some things and i found a diffrent problem:
this time it doesnt deform the ball but the arm...
and i also noticed the most left ball doesnt deform the body?! is this because it isnt overlapsed?

[image]

Comment: Did you parent using automatic weights? A bone affects all vertices in its vertex group, so vertices that shouldn't be deformed need to have a weight of zero or not belong to that vertex group at all. However, if sliding the block along the surface of the sphere is your only goal, then there are simpler ways than rigging.

Comment: The documentation has lots of information on armature and armature weights: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Upper_body_weight_painting

Comment: @DuaneDibbley i am very new to rigging in blender. can you give me some steps to solve this? and yes i used automatic weights.

Comment: I do mainly stills, and consequently I don't do much rigging. I have done some rudimentary armature animations in the past, and I could probably get this working for you, but you'd most likely get better help by taking some general rigging/weight painting tutorials. Perhaps [this one](https://youtu.be/xKPOL_u6hms) will be helpful.